# Knockout.JS - Run function when clicking outside of div

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to execute a function when clicking outside of div using knockout. I attempted to do so by using the event binding with blur.  I think I am close, I just need a little help.

The filterFromList function works fine.

Relevant JS

```
self.filterFromList = function (item) {
    self.selectedName(item.name);
    self.location().forEach(function(place) {
        if (place.name === self.selectedName()) {
            place.showLocation(true);
            place.marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            place.showLocation(false);
            place.marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
};

self.unfilter = function (item) {
    console.log("blurring");
    self.location().forEach(function (place) {
        place.showLocation(true);
        place.marker.setVisible(true);
    })
};
```

Relevant HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: location">
<a class="location-click" data-bind="click: $parent.filterFromList, event: { blur: $parent.unfilter }">
    <li class="location-block" data-bind="visible: showLocation">
        <img class="location-img" data-bind="attr: {src: imgURL}" />
        <h4 data-bind="text: name"></h4>
        <hr>
    </li>
</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: What div are you referring to when you say "when clicking outside of div"? Is that around your <ul>?

Comment: I'd also like to know why would you do that - clicking pretty much anywhere other than a button with a filter role to clear a filter is everything but user friendly. Even clicking the 'details' button or link or something like that would erase the filter. Just add a clear filter button or implement toggle on the existing ones.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a custom bindingHandler ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zvv5jrr/15/)):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickOutside = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var fn = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    $('html').on('click', function(e) {
      if (!($.contains(element, e.target) || element === e.target)) {
        fn();
      }
    });
  },
}

var vm = {
  clickOutside: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

HTML:

```
<div style="background-color:green;">
  Outside area
  <div data-bind="clickOutside: clickOutside.bind($data, 'clicked outside of red div')" style="background-color:red;">
  inside area
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically the idea is that you add an event listener to the outermost element possible (`<html>`), and check whether the click target is directly or indirectly inside (`$.contains(what contains, what is contained)`) the desired container. If so, then do nothing, if not, then call the bound function.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by adding a tabindex attribute to the div in question.  Thank you for your help!

```
<a class="location-click" tabindex="0" data-bind="click: $parent.filterFromList, event: { blur: $parent.unfilter } ">
            <li class="location-block" data-bind="visible: showLocation">
                <img class="location-img" data-bind="attr: {src: imgURL}"></img>
                <h4 data-bind="text: name"></h4>
                <hr>
            </li>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

attention don't work weel with knockout binding like (if and with )
first time you show element container init go well, and if you hide and show again, click outside don't work anymore

, insteade use :

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.clickOutside = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var fn = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor().fn);
            var uid = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor().uid);
            $('html').on('click', function (e) {
                if ($(e.target).parents('.' + uid).length === 0) {
                    fn();
                }
            });
        },
    }
```

assign an UID to the parent, then this is working with 'with' and 'if' binding